# JFrame does not display on ubuntu

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with net beans and swing running on ubuntu, when i run a JFrame everything runs ok but it does not display. Just to say the JFrame is created and no changes have been made.

Comment: Couldn't tell without seeing some code. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And then edit your post with one.

Comment: Please share some of your code. Did you try on another OS?

Comment: Share some code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fount a solution as it seems the JFrame did not where to display i have two monitos and coordinates must have been wrong when I set the JFrame to display in center then it displayed.

Comment: *"when I set the JFrame to display in center then it displayed."*  Better to calls `setLocationByPlatform(true)`..